# Google Analytics - Individual Profiles based on a query param

Tags: google-analytics

I have a website which effectively displays a different site based on a URL Query Paramater existing:

For Example:

```
www.mysite.com/?i=1 (will display "Site A")
www.mysite.com/?i=2 (will displays "Site B")
... and so-on ...
```

I need to setup a completely different set of reports for each site based on that query paramater, but can't see how (or if) this can be done.

Also, it is possible that the URL could display as www.mystring.com/?something=99&i=1, so needs to be on the paramater existing, not the url pattern.

Further to this .. I am able to control the inclusion of the appropriate javascript based on which Query value is passed in, I just can't work out how to create individual profiles (thus seperate scripts) for each site.

I hope this makes sense.

Many Thanks in advance.

Jason

Comment: Why the down vote??  I have read over my post a few times and just can't see why ??  Down voter, care to share your reason so that I don't do it again??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to use the same javascript on all the sites, and use profile filters to track the different sites. (See http://support.google.com/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1033162 for more info about filters)

To do this, you'll need to

1. Create a profile for each report, under the mysite.com property.
2. Create a filter for each report, and apply the filter to the report profile. For URLs like you described, you'll want to use a `custom filter`, that `includes` the filter field `Request URI`, with a filter pattern like `.*i=1$` assuming the i=1 parameter is always at the end. (more info about filters at https://support.google.com/googleanalytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&utm_id=ad&answer=55582)

Be aware that filters aren't retroactive -- they only apply to new tracking data coming in, not data that's already been recorded.

Also be aware that there are limits to the number of profiles you can have per analytics account -- it used to be 50 profiles, but we were able to get that bumped to 100 through a special request.

Comment: Thanks Mike, I will have a play with this and let you know how it goes.

Comment: @Jason, I don't know how many sites you have to deal with... you should also know that there's limit's to the number of profiles per account.

Comment: Thanks Mike.. good to know.. there could potentially be quite a few.  I may need to create seperate accounts for each filter anyway, as I need to give access to reports to different people.  I think filters are going to be the way to go, it is just how I create the accounts to maange these filters that will be the trick.  Will keep you posted.  Thanks!

Comment: Mike, thanks again.  There was a bit of reading and playing around, but your pointers gave me what I needed to do it. THANKS!